# Need guidance on parsing some API data

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I working on a project where I am writing scraper bots to retrieve information direct from a websites api. I have come across something I've not seen before and could use some help getting the data parsed, if at all possible.

Here is the data I am retrieving from the API using python requests: https://pastebin.com/LMwNMFUg

```
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.blacktype.bet',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'dnt': '1',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.blacktype.bet/',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'cookie': 'JSESSIONID="OLSPgxtIG1W2eHIh-sXca80AB1Szr8F0V6J5gMqb.app2.rs.fsbtech.com:app2.rs.fsbtech.com-wildfly-fsbapi-server"; languageId=1; localeKey=en; siteId=1; visid_incap_1054556=uiVi8yfPQpeJHLvPtDckCv7WWV8AAAAAQUIPAAAAAABJt9bOcysr/h1j3vxhYBGi; _ga=GA1.2.1922055854.1599723264; clid=b071ab93-61fa-4c48-d7a0-616daaa095f8; autoPlay=true; sib_cuid=a455abe6-28f3-43bf-a365-6dd94105fc38; currencyCode=GBP; incap_ses_873_1054556=mFJGdXsmIFNrI9aT+YQdDDUNY18AAAAAmN4GnAX9apbD0wxbVt+CJQ==; betslip-notification=0; betslip-clear=0; _gid=GA1.2.1521194465.1600326966; eventCountry=GB; JSESSIONID="CqPav2ZP6d3ytJx4w6BB4fuarMU12_qMViZ_8pET.app1.rs.fsbtech.com:app1.rs.fsbtech.com-wildfly"; JSESSIONID="OLSPgxtIG1W2eHIh-sXca80AB1Szr8F0V6J5gMqb.app1.rs.fsbtech.com:app1.rs.fsbtech.com-wildfly-fsbapi-server"',
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}
url = "https://www.blacktype.bet/fsb-api-rest/racing/future/5/HORSES.fsb"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

And here is the API URL: https://www.blacktype.bet/fsb-api-rest/racing/future/5/HORSES.fsb

Can anyone offer some direction? Can it even be done?

Thanks in advance chaps!

Answer (score 1):

This website uses **[msgpack](https://github.com/msgpack)** javascript module for parsing this kind of data.

```
import msgpack from "@msgpack/msgpack";
import fs from 'fs';

let data = fs.readFileSync('/Users/<username>/Downloads/HORSES.fsb');

let d = msgpack.decode(data);
let keys = Object.keys(d.__s).reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = d.__s[c].split('|'), a), {});
const res = d.response;

const recurseArray = (a) => {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        if (a.length && Object.keys(keys).includes(a[0])) {
            const k = a.shift();
            return a.reduce((a, c, ci) => (a[keys[k][ci]] = recurseArray(c), a), {});
        }
        else {
            return a.map(recurseArray);
        }
    }
    else {
        return a;
    }
};

const dt = recurseArray(res);

console.log(JSON.stringify(dt, null, 2));
```

Using the code, you can dump the JSON file representation to your stdout.

Answer (score 0):

That URL points to the file, which you want to download. In order to download the file with `requests` library you should do something like this:

```py
url = 'https://www.blacktype.bet/fsb-api-rest/racing/future/5/HORSES.fsb'
response = requests.get(url)
filename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Please refer to:

1. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content (to read about `content` attribute of a response)
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open (to see about  `wb` mode)

Comment: And that would allow me to correctly parse the data inside the file instead of being unreadable?

Comment: That will let you to download that file "as is". Parsing is another topic. Do you know that file format?

Comment: As soon as you know the file format - you can easily parse it. For example, first thing I found about "fsb" files is this one https://github.com/HearthSim/python-fsb5

Comment: But most likely in your case it's something different (file format)

Comment: This is a data file, fsb5 is for audio files. The backend is powered by fsbtech.com so I’m guessing it maybe proprietary and not possible to decode.